# Flutter hot reload not working when I try to make changes in the app

Tags: flutter, dart

```
To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
```

I am trying to make some changes in the flutter app and when I run `flutter run`, the app could launch normally but even when I press "r" or "R" to load some changes it could not work so anyone know where to press the R button in order to load some changes in the app?

Comment: move your pointer to terminal, then press r/R

Comment: @Nguyenfamily I would hope that's what he did.

Comment: It worked after I press r from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Hot Reload is very useful for checking quick changes while coding, however this may not be possible in some occasions like:

- Adding imports to new library's.
- When you add new assets to the project, like images.
- When you create an error in the code, making it not to compiling.

There might be other reasons for the code to not Hot Reload, however these are some of the ones I've encountered mostly when developing for Android.

When I can't reload the app, the best option usually is to stop and build again.

Except if you have an error in the code. In that case, you must fix it before build, (obviously).